# django search on comma separated string

Tags: python, django

**Models.py**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    keyword = models.CharField(max_lenght=300)
```

here in **keyword** field keyword's  are storing as a comma separated string
format

such as: **Medical Photo,Human Body,Body**.

now i am trying to search photo on the comma separated string.

to do this i write the following query

```
keysearch = request.GET.get('format')

qr = Q(keyword__icontains=keysearch)
searched_image = Photo.objects.filter(qr).all()
```

i have getting the keywords value through **get** method as following

```
{% for keyword in keywords %}<h5><a href="{% url 'keywordSearch' %}?format=keyword"><span class="label label-default">{{keyword}}</span></a>{%endfor%}
```

and this is `url`

```
url(r'^keyword_search_result/$',views.keywordSearch,name = 'keywordSearch')
```

here in mention the **keywords** in the for loop is infact a `list of keywords` fetching from the following view

```
def ImageKeywords(request,image_id):
    image_keywords = get_object_or_404(Photo,pk = image_id)
    keywords = image_keywords.keyword.split(',')

    return render_to_response('search/keyword_search_results.html',{'keywords': keywords},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

now the problem is, no results are showing in my `search results` page.is there any problem in my query?

Comment: your url will always be `keyword_search_result/?format=keyword` (the `keyword` won't change, since you have hard coded it) - so unless you have objects that have the word `'keyword'` as a tag, it won't work.

Comment: should i enclose  the keyword within quotation,such as `{% url 'keywordSearch' %}?   format="keyword"`? @BurhanKhalid

Comment: no i don't think so that it will solve the problem.enclosing `keyword` in a quotation,then is there any alternative way to get the **value** of the selected  `keyword` throung the GET method ?@BurhanKhalid

Comment: If you view source of the page that has the search links, you will see that all the links are exactly the same - this is your basic problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `a href` like this

```
<a href="{% url 'keywordSearch' %}?format={{keyword}}">
```